# Working with ranges of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and that $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear maps from $V \to W$. If the range of $T_1$ is contained in the range of $T_2$, show that there is an operator $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $T_1 = T_2S$.

How would one go about proving this? Isn't this trivial since range $T_1 \subset T_2$?

Comment: The best way to prove these things usually is just to construct $S$. If it's trivial, $S$ will be trivial to construct!

Comment: Would something like the following work... For $x\in V$, Let $T_1(v) = w$, $T_2(v) = z$, where $w\in \text{range } T_1$ and $z\in \text{range } T_2$. Then $\exists S$ where $Sz=w$ since range $T_1\subset$ range  $T_2$?

Comment: Be careful - what is $S$ here? I don't think it acts on elements of $W$, which your $w$ and $z$ are, here. It's an operator on $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should probably construct $S$ in such examples. In showing existence of something, it's frequently (although not always) the case that just constructing the thing is the best proof!

If $im(T_1) \subseteq im(T_2) \implies \forall \; x \in V, T_1(x) = T_2(y)$ for some $y \in V$.

What you want to prove is that there is an operator $S$ such that $T_1 = T_2S$, i.e. $\forall \; x \in V, T_1(x) = T_2(S(x)).$

I haven't given you much extra information, apart from rewriting the question, but hopefully you can see how to construct $S$, given the above, in order to make this go.

Comment: Would letting $S=T_2^{-1}T_1$ be considered too trivial? I understand the proof intuitively, but am struggling to define a concrete mapping.

Comment: Not if you haven't got a good reason to think that $T_2^{-1}$ exists.